# Flutter java.lang.NullPointerException on integrating some plugins

Tags: flutter, paytm

There are some plugins such as https://github.com/mrdishant/Paytm-Flutter-Plugin

which I am trying to integrate. 
But I am receiving this error:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.PackageManager android.content.Context.getPackageManager()' on a null object reference

It is happening with a few plugins not just this one. So I recon the problem might not be with this specific plugin but something different?

Comment: This is not the paytm official plugin, we are in process to develop the plugin and update the detail once ready. For the supported plugins currently on paytm payment gateway please refer to the link https://developer.paytm.com/docs/plugins/.

Answer (score 0):

There is a one plugin available for doing this called [paytmkaro](https://pub.dev/packages/paytmkaro) you use this but it's only work with production keys.
You can use this because its more easier to use.

Before starting upload the server side code on server which is available on their documentation which is available [here](https://github.com/codersanket/Paytm-Server-code) please don't make any changes on server side code it's used to generate a txn token on paytm server.

Change the minimum sdk version to 19

and just copy paste this code

```
` try {
  PaytmResponse paymentResponse = await _paytmKaro.startTransaction(
    url: serverside code url e.g. https://arcane-temple-61754.herokuapp.com/intiateTansection.php,
    mid: your Production merchant id,
    mkey: your merchant key,
    customerId:customer id (must be unique for every customer),
    amount: transection amount,
    orderId: Order Id (Order id must be unique Everytime for every order),
  );

  if(paymentResponse.status=="TXN_SUCCESS"){
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>txnSuccessful(paytmResponse: paymentResponse,)));
  }
  else if(paymentResponse.status=="TXN_FAILURE"){
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>txnFailed(paytmResponse: paymentResponse,)));
  }
} 
catch(e){
  print(e);
  key.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(e.toString())));      // platformVersion = 'Failed to get platform version.'
}`
```

and you are done.